# After Core Update 8.5.9 to 8.6.7 404 page for anonymous user

Tags: 8

After i updated my drupal core from 8.5.9 to 8.6.7 some pages aren't reachable for anonymous users (error 404), but when I'am logged in everything is showing up correct.

Sometimes I get an error (not there before the update):

```
    Notice: Undefined index: status in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->loadFromSharedTables() (line 555 of <PATH TO SITE>/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php) #0
```

could there be a link between this 2 "problems"?

I already tested a module which should solve this problem, but it didn't.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Regards

M.

Comment: Did you run `yourwebsite.com/update.php`? flushed all caches?

Comment: sure... several times...

Comment: It seems to be a problem with a entity definition, if you have access to `drush` you should try to run `drush updb --entity-updates`

Comment: sry doesn't worked